# how to clear a select from tags and get the value through a space

Tags: php

I have a select

```
<select>
  <option>Hello</option>
  <option>World</option>
  <option>Stackoverflow</option>
</select>
```

And I need to get words without tags in a line with a space. Exp: "Hello World Stackoverflow"

UPD:

```
$att_text = strip_tags("<select><option>Hello</option><option>World</option><option>Stackoverflow</option></select>");
  $att_text1 = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', " ", $att_text);
```

This final code

```
$att_text1 = strip_tags (str_replace('</option>', " ", $att_text));
```

Comment: `strip_tags` or html parser.

Comment: I get the php variable select. I tried through strip_tags, does not exceed

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please post some code. This community is not meant to write code for you.

Comment: UPD: add code..

Comment: I don't see any `\n` in your string.

Comment: How correctly to clean tags and words through a gap to make?

Comment: thx guys, I found the problem and solved it

Comment: I was wrong did not help me